# Where can I see the meaning of warnings in R?

Tags: r

Also for my case, when I try to fit a poisson regression model with glm I got following warning

```
glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred
```

What does this indicates? Where can I find meanings of this warning in R package?

Comment: for this particular one, you might find what you're looking for here http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Poisson-GLM-warning-message-td3067631.html

Comment: how much data do you have

Comment: Hi, I did a greedy search like simulation for poisson regression. In one extreme case, I try to fit the model where the number of parameters =  num of Observations. Whether it caused problem? But i tried it several times, sometimes, no warning, sometimes, warnings

Comment: @hrbrmstr  so,if I did a simulation study, it could happen even my coding is all right. I do not need to really worry about them?